# Get a value of an class in an array

Tags: php, arrays

Im a php beginner and want to do the following:
When I var_dump a function called get_values(), this is the output:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#1033 (9) { 
        ["sub_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["sub_email"]=> string(18) "mail@site.com" 
        ["sub_name"]=> string(7) "John" 
        ["sub_last_name"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["sub_key"]=> string(34) "..." 
        ["created"]=> string(19) "2015-02-17 11:37:49" 
        ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["sola_nl_mail_sent"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["sola_nl_mail_sending_time"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
    } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#858 (9) { 
        ["sub_id"]=> string(2) "10" 
        ["sub_email"]=> string(19) "mail2@site.com" 
        ["sub_name"]=> string(8) "Doe" 
        ["sub_last_name"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["sub_key"]=> string(34) "..." 
        ["created"]=> string(19) "2015-02-24 03:04:58" 
        ["status"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["sola_nl_mail_sent"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["sola_nl_mail_sending_time"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" 
    }
}
```

Now I want to output an array, that contains only the emails:

$emails = array('mail@site.com','mail2@site.com');

Can somebody help me, archiving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $data = get_values();
    $emails = array();

    foreach($data as $v)
        $emails[] = $v->sub_email;

    print_r($emails);

?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

User [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) :

```
$arrData = get_values();
$emails = array();
foreach($arrData as $val) {
    $emails[] = $val->sub_email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$emails = array_map(function ($value) {
    return $value->sub_email;
}, get_values());
```